# Multiple Models with XNA

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, xna, xna-4.0

hi first i want you to know, that i'm new to XNA.

I created a XNA Application for a Surface. In my App i'm drawing a fbx Model. My Problem is, that i don't know how to draw more than one Model. Here is my code, so you can see how i am drawing:

```
protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        if (!applicationLoadCompleteSignalled)
        {
            // Dismiss the loading screen now that we are starting to draw
            ApplicationServices.SignalApplicationLoadComplete();
            applicationLoadCompleteSignalled = true;
        }

        graphics.GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);

        rot += 0.0005f;

        foreach(Model model in modelList)
        {
            DrawModel(model);
        }

        graphics.GraphicsDevice.DepthStencilState = DepthStencilState.Default;

        base.Draw(gameTime);
    }

    private void DrawModel(Model myModel)
    {
        foreach (ModelMesh mesh in myModel.Meshes)
        {
            foreach (BasicEffect effect in mesh.Effects)
            {
                effect.EnableDefaultLighting();  // Beleuchtung aktivieren
                effect.World = Matrix.CreateRotationZ(rot) * worldMatrix;
                effect.View = viewMatrix;

                effect.Projection = projectionMatrix;
            }
            mesh.Draw();
        }
    }
```

The model which is displayed first is only a plane. Now i want to add a cube, so i am calling this in my Update:

```
if(Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input.Keys.A))
        {
            LoadModel("cube");
        }
```

LoadModel(String) just loads the Model and adds it to the modelList. But the cube is not displayed.

Thanks for helping me out.

Comment: Looks like you are storing your models in modelList. You should be able to draw everything that is in that list. So just add some more Models to the modelList. In LoadContent() I guess.

Comment: I want to add a new Model to the List with LoadModel when the A-Key is pressed. But nothing changes. But the problem is not in the LoadModel() becuase the plane is loaded at the beginning with this function. Even if i load the cube after the plane at the beginning (in LoadContent()) the cube is not displayed.

Comment: You will have to add far more information to your question to make it possible for others to analyze your problem. How does your LoadModel()-method look like? What do you want to draw and what does the programm actually draw? How does your entire Game-Class look like?

Comment: Further it would propably be a good idea to create individual classes which Load, Draw and Update the logic for different models/shapes you want to draw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like in the above code snippet, there are no errors. It would be nice to look at the method LoadModel.

While only advice:

1. Look in debug mode what is happening: the cube does not exist at all (not loaded) or whether it was loaded, but not drawn. Maybe it's the shader or object correctly positioned relative to the camera.
2. Not the best option so just call a method on the condition that the button is pressed. In this case, it will run several times while you hold the button as the check occurs very often (typically 60 times per second). Would have to add a flag or check if they are certainly not in the method LoadModel.

**EDIT**

The code seems correct but there is some strange in this situation. If you call your LoadModel method you should have an exception if something wrong with model or null in your collection. I think that in some reason your method not execute at all. Try load your model it in LoadContent methot directly, then try call LoadModel from LoadContent.

Hint: separate code lines.
For example use

```
Model model = Content.Load<Model>(name);
modelList.Add(model);
```

instead of

```
modelList.Add(Content.Load<Model>(name));
```

It makes much easy debug your code.

Comment: Point 2 seems to be a good hint. maybe he just needs to create and set a flag like isDrawn = true; or something.

Comment: It works, the cube was laying under the plane (don't sure why the it lays there ... it should be on top). Of course it is obvious that this can happen but i didn't thought that this would be the case because if i make an output of the modellist in the console it seems that only one element is in the list. And thanks for point 2. Good hint!

Comment: Thanks, @user3707057. Cube may lie below the plane, for example, if the axis in 3d-editor arranged differently than in XNA (like in 3DMax). For example, if Y look up and cube occupies volume from (0, 0, 0) to (1, 1, 1), it is rotated 90 degrees and would be, as it were below the zero plane. Axis Z become Y, and Y become -Z. I call it "Fall face down on the floor" :D

Answer (score 0):

I changed my Code that it looks like that:

```
if(Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input.Keys.A))
        {
            if (pressKey)
            {
                LoadModel("cube");
                pressKey = false;
            }
        }

        if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyUp(Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input.Keys.A))
        {
            pressKey = true;
        }
```

My LoadModel looks like that:

```
private void LoadModel(String name)
    {
        modelList.Add(Content.Load<Model>(name));
    }
```

If i make a Consoleoutput after i added the cube to the list there is still only the plane. I don't know what the problem is. The code seems correct to me.

Comment: Okay sorry, i solved it. The Models were just laying under the plane. Sorry for don't recognizing this but im still confused because they are there but if i make Console.WriteLine(modelList) There is only one Model in the list.